# is there a pendant to "select-> Shift select -> ctlr-P -> parent -> keep transform" manually settings parents in the properties?

Tags: parent

is there a pendant to "select-> Shift select -> ctlr-P -> parent -> keep transform" parent settings in the properties?

I searched in properties but i couldn't find "keep offset" under "parenting".

Comment: Well, the problem with this is that "keep transforms" and "keep offset" are two different things. The transformations are what is done to the object in relation to its reference point's location, rotation and scale. This is either the world center or the parent's origin and transformation. The offset between two objects is determined by the differences in location, rotation and scale in relation to a mutual reference point, the world center usually. I'm sure you are aware of these things, I guess the question is (since there is no such option) what you would want as workaround? A script maybe?

Comment: thanks for that explanation. I didn't even was aware of that difference...‍♂️ i still have a lot to learn...! - so you DO overestimate me

Comment: Of course I'm oversimplifying here. I think you can only do this by calculating the differences between the two objects and inserting them into the transformation values after parenting.

Comment: By the way, the _Parent_ > _Object (Keep Transform)_ option doesn't make any difference to the simple _Parent_ > _Object_ if you are not changing the parent from one to another.